# Q: What is nodeos exception: unrecognised option 'wallet-dir'

Tags: nodeos, ubuntu

Just downloaded eosio v1.3.0 and tried to run nodes but get the following exception:

`~/eos/build/programs $ nodeos
2018-09-23T15:25:41.459 thread-0   main.cpp:136                  main                 ] Throw location unknown (consider using BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION)
Dynamic exception type: boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::program_options::unknown_option> >
std::exception::what: unrecognised option 'wallet-dir'`

What boost program is getting this error and how can I set the `wallet-dir` variable to resolve the issue?

Comment: I think you need to change your config.ini you are using old config.ini file.

Answer (score 1):

[Solved] You can find the correct config.ini file from the [developers portal](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/configuration-file). (I was altering the wrong config.ini file earlier.)

In the `.local/share/eosio/nodeos/config/config.ini` file, commenting out the `unlock-timeout` and `wallet-dir` settings fixed the problem.

Comment: Yes exactly the path is `.local/share/eosio/nodeos/config/config.ini`. I don't use docker  so in my case this is easy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your config.ini file.

**Unknown configuration items in config.ini will now error on startup (#5678)**

Prior to 1.3.0 unknown configuration items in config.ini would be silently ignored. This behavior has been changed in 1.3.0 to an error that prevents startup of nodeos. **Users with old auto-generated config.ini files may need to remove some options** that are no longer available in nodeos for example **wallet-dir** or **unlock-timeout**

For more info you can go https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/releases and check **v1.3.0 release**. There are other changes also.

Comment: So I did a complete rebuild, using the v1.3.0 version from github, which removed all the old configuration files, but I still get the same error `unrecognised option 'wallet-dir'`. Now I can only see the `config.ini` under eos/Docker/ directory and no where else (and I'm not using Docker)....So where else is the `wallet-dir` being set or passed as an argument to nodeos?